# Selenium chrome remote web driver deosn't work on vpn

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I'm using Selenium remote web driver for gui testing. The server is on Linux, the browser is on Windows. Everything works fine when I'm using a 'regular' connection. The first issue is that when I switch from cable to wifi, I have to restart the computer for the remote webdriver to work. But the main problem, is that when connecting to vpn, nothing works at all - the browser won't even open. Has anyone encountered anything like this in the past?
Let me know if more details are required..
Thanks :)

Comment: can you edit the question and show the part of code where you try to connect to vpn?

Comment: Hi,
Connection to vpn isn't sone via code, it's from a separate tool that lets me connect to my work's network. What I have in code is just the connection to the remote webdriver

Comment: maybe when using VPN the IP of the computer is changed. Or, the VPN does not actually allow direct connection to the computer. Or, the connection is possible but only from computers on same VPN. Long story short, I would investigate the VPN rather than Selenium code

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't allow extensions while running /controlled by selenium. I end up using VPN application(hide me,norvpn) which globally change ip for the running applications on my machine.